# JPA query "optimization"

Tags: jpa, ejb, eclipselink

I have just turned on query logging in the database behing JPA (EclipseLink) and have witnessed the horror of JPA "optimization" and "caching".

For example, doing a simple JPA query like this:

```
 SELECT p FROM Picklist p;
```

... will cause a JPA to do a million of SQL queries to database (one query for each record, so select * from picklist where id=[...]). And Picklist is a simple entity!

Why doesn't it do a SELECT * FROM Picklist and just does everything else (filling the Persistance Context or whatever) in memory?

Does it need some special switch to tell it to do this? Why is it working like this?

Comment: why isn't SELECT p FROM Picklist p; ? without (Picklist p)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check the JPA Query

```
SELECT Picklist p FROM Picklist p;
```

this should be

```
SELECT p FROM Picklist p;
```

Second you need to understand that you cannot make a `Select *` because when you do a query of that type you're bring more information that just the columns.

Third remember that Hibernate need to translate the query to each database, to provide that functionality some performance could loose because it's Sql Native never the less this have been improve with each new version and if you need an extremely performance. Use a Normal Sql Query that you perfectly can use and handle the records

Answer (score 1):

JPA provides many different query optimization techniques, but if you don't use any of these, you can cause unnecessary queries.

I assume you are seeing queries for relationships of the Picklist, although the exact query you are using, the mappings for Picklist, and the SQL would help.

To see how to optimize relationships

see,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

Comment: So for example, I have a Customer which has several fields, which are Picklist entity, i.e. for customerType and industryType. Now I call 5 times daoPicklist.getByName("partner") and I get a Picklist and assign it to an existing Customer entity and merge it. This daoPicklist.getByName(...) is called many times in the (different modules of the) code to retrieve the Picklist. But what happens when I look at the database query logs is that each time I call this method, SQL query is performed! So there is no caching at all.

Comment: what does daoPicklist.getByName(...) do?  If it executes a query not by Id then it will always access the database, unless you enable a query cache.